# How do I make a HTML Markup using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have a function, the function adds note objects to the HTML UI.

The note object is structured like this :

```
{
   id,
   text,
   date,
   links : [
      { link,
        linkText
      }
   ]
}
```

The function that I used to add the note object to an un-ordered list ()

```
function addNoteToListUI(note) {
  $("#notesList").prepend("<li id='"+note.id+"'>" + note.text + "<div class='buttons'><button class='remove'>" + removeSVG + "</button></div></li>");
}
```

The problem that I have with this function is: 
If a note has links, I want to add those links to the UI as a hyperlink in an 'a' tag for example:

```
let note = {
   id : 1,
   text : 'this is a simple note with a link and another link',
   date : '2018/01/01',
   links : [ {link : 'https://simple.com', text : 'link'},
             {link : 'https://simple2.com', text : 'another link'} ]
}
```

The expected result:

```
"<li id='"+note.id+"'> this is a simple note with a <a href ='https://simple.com'>link</a> and <a href ='https://simple2.com'>another link</a><div class='buttons'><button class='remove'>" + removeSVG + "</button></div></li>"
```

This is what is tried but it didn't work:

```
function addNoteToListUI(note) {
  let text = "<li id='"+ note.id +"'>";
  if(note.links !== undefined){
    note.links.forEach(link => {
      note.text.replace(RegExp(link.linkText, 'ig'), (match) => {
        text += "<a href='"+link.link+"'>"+match+"</a>"
        return match;
      });
    });
  }
  $("#notesList").prepend("note.text + "<div class='buttons'><button class='remove'>" + removeSVG + "</button></div></li>");
}
```

The problem with this is as obvious it only adding the links the other text, is left

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I see two JS objects in that array. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your links array guaranteed to be in the same order as the where the links should be inserted? And will each member of the link array correspond to only one link?

Comment: @Mark_M: I was looking at the 'shorthand' Object in the first code block. The problem I saw doesn't appear to be preserved in the populated Object. (I've deleted my original comment.)

Comment: `replace()` doesn't alter the contents of the variable. You have to do `note.text=note.text.replace()`. Also you have an error on your las sentence, maybe it was just a typo when posting here.

Comment: It might help if you use RegExp friendly phrases for example you have one set to link and the other set to another link but the one set to long will flag both the first one and the second one because they both contain link while the second one will only flag the second one. Also you have the quotation marks mixed up on your last function you need to take the quotation marks before note.text out. And you put everything in the text variable but you never reapply that variable to note.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating through the links without actually updating any markup. Also, with this setup it's going to be difficult to replace links without running into ambiguity. For example, what if part of one link is the actual text of another link?

`"link"` would replace the text of both "link" and "another link" in your example, which seems undesirable

I would suggest using some kind of symbol to denote "links" (for example {{link}}).
I would also suggest separating logic into more functions so it is easier to reason about.

Here is an example:

```js
let note = {
  id: 1,
  text: 'this is a simple note with a {{link}} and {{another link}}',
  date: '2018/01/01',
  // note, "links" has been refactored into an object for ease of lookup
  links: {
    link: {
      link: 'https://simple.com',
      text: 'link'
    },
    'another link': {
      link: 'https://simple2.com',
      text: 'another link'
    }
  }
}

const linkToHTML = link => `
  <a href="${link.link}">${link.text}</a>
`

const resolvePlaceholders = (text, links) => 
  text.replace(/{{([^}]*)}}/ig, (match, $1) =>
    links[$1] ? linkToHTML(links[$1]) : match)

const noteToHTML = note => `
  <li class="note" id="${note.id}">
    ${resolvePlaceholders(note.text, note.links)}
    <div class="note-buttons">
      <button class="remove">X</button>
    </div>
  </li>
`

const prependNote = note => $('#notesList').prepend(noteToHTML(note))

prependNote(note)
```

```css
.note {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="notesList"></ul>
```

Comment: I get the algorithm idea, i modified your code to fit my need, thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The links list is ambiguous because the first `link` text matches both `link` and `another link`. So this answer depends on the list of links being in the order they will be found and only matching once. Otherwise the first `link` will match in two places and it's hard to know which was intended.

You can use `reduce()` with the links array and pass in the text as the second argument. This will create your text with the anchors in place:

```
let t = note.links.reduce((a,c) => a.replace(RegExp(c.text), '<a href="' + c.link + '">' + c.text + '</a>'), note.text)
```

Now it's just a matter of adding that to your list element and you end up with a tidy, two-line function:

```js
let note = {id : 1,text : 'this is a simple note with a link and another link',date : '2018/01/01',links : [ {link : 'https://simple.com', text : 'link'},{link : 'https://simple2.com', text : 'another link'} ] }

function makeNote(note){
    let t = note.links.reduce((a,c) => a.replace(RegExp(c.text), '<a href="' + c.link + '">' + c.text + '</a>'), note.text)
    return "<li id='"+ note.id +"'>" + t + "</li>";
}

$("#notesList").prepend(makeNote(note))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="notesList"></ul>
```